# how to disable text field and combo box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I'm having a problem in disabling textbox and combo box by using another combo box here is my javascript so far:

```
 category.onchange = function () {
 var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;   
 document.getElementById("bos").disabled = (val == "Military","Civilian") ? true : false;
 document.getElementById("afpsn").disabled = (val ==  "Dependent","Civilian") ? true : false;
};
```

and here's my html:

```
<select name="category" size="1" id="category">
  <option selected="selected">Choose...</option>
  <option value="Civilian">Civilian</option>
  <option value="Military">Military</option>
  <option value="Dependent">Dependent</option>
            </select>

  <select name="bos" id="bos" >
  <option value="">Branch of Service</option>
  <option value="PAF">PAF</option>
  <option value="PA">PA</option>
  <option value="PN">PN</option>
  <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
</select>

  <input id = "afpsn"  name="afpsn" type="text" id="afpsn" size="38" placeholder="AFPSN" />
```

it should be whenever I select dependent or civilian the other combo box and text field will be disabled and will be enable when I select military. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmanbashirov/wLJnF/)  will be help you. you can edit logic , too.

```
category.onchange = function () {
 var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; 
  //  alert(val);
 document.getElementById("bos").disabled = (val === "Military") ? false : true;
    document.getElementById("afpsn").disabled = (val === "Military") ? false : true;
 document.getElementById("afpsn").disabled = (val ===  "Dependent" || val ===  "Civilian" ) ? true : false;
 document.getElementById("bos").disabled = (val ===  "Dependent" || val ===  "Civilian" ) ? true : false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

Your condition (comparison with `strings`) is incorrect.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/A4HJS/)

```
category.onchange = function () {
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("bos").disabled = (val === "Military" || val === "Civilian") ? true : false;
    document.getElementById("afpsn").disabled = (val === "Dependent" || val === "Civilian") ? true : false;
};
```

**EDIT**:

To attach the event on page load (assuming you are not using jQuery), one way is to attach it on pageload like:

```
function init() {
    category.onchange = function () {
        var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("bos").disabled = (val === "Military" || val === "Civilian") ? true : false;
        document.getElementById("afpsn").disabled = (val === "Dependent" || val === "Civilian") ? true : false;
    };
}
```

and something like this on your `<body>`

```
<body onload="init();">
   ...
</body>
```

The reason why the example worked is that `jsfiddle.net` loads the functions in the js box on load by default. But in your case, you have to do that manually.

Comment: why it won't work in my page?? It doesn't have any jquery library, is it?

Comment: Your code and this solution does not need any jQuery. You can see that the fiddle link above does not include any jQuery.

Comment: now having problem putting it on my page... why it won't work? :(

Comment: maybe you are forgetting to attach the event on body onload?

Comment: how to attach it? what should i do?

Comment: No problem. Please choose answers that best helped your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is anything like `(val == "Military","Civilian")`
 [You can try this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmGL8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
/*Function to check if value is in an array*/
function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
/*******************************************/

var s=document.getElementById("elementId");
s.disabled = isInArray(s.value,["Military","Civilian"]); //Function automatically returns "true" or "false" depending on value
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ygz3u/)